# How to stop kubelet service running in an RKE kubernetes worker node

Tags: kubernetes

I need to simulate Node "NotReady" status for a node and tried to stop kubelet to achieve that. But am getting the below error. Looks like this is not the right command for my k8s environment. I need this to verify the working of taints and tolerations.

systemctl stop kubelet.service

Failed to stop kubelet.service: Unit kubelet.service not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RKE is a K8s distribution that runs entirely within Docker containers as per [documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/). That means that none of the K8s services are native Linux services. Try `docker ps`, and you'll find a container named `kubelet` running (among others).

So to stop kubelet service on RKE clusters, you'll need to stop the container:

```
docker stop kubelet
```

Comment: Sorry about the delayed acceptance. I had meanwhile found the answer by looking at the RKE documentation and didn't come back here.

Answer (score -1):

To use `systemctl stop kubelet`, first this needs to be added to systemd by running command `systemctl enable kubelet`  post that stop command can be used to stop the kubelet.

By running `ps -ef` kubelet process can be identified and stop it.